# radius request gives wrong values

Tags: c, sockets, dhcp, radius-protocol

```
if (rc_avpair_add(rh, &send, PW_USER_PASSWORD, passwd, -1, 0) == NULL)
                return ERROR_RC;

        if (rc_avpair_add(rh, &send, PW_NAS_PORT_TYPE, nas_port_type, -1, 0) == NULL)
                return ERROR_RC;

        if (rc_avpair_add(rh, &send, PW_FRAMED_IP_ADDRESS,"172.17.14.90", -1, 0) == NULL)
                return ERROR_RC;
```

above is my part of code "`radexample.c` Which used for generating a " radius request" I want to pass Framed IP with it also. my issue is here PW_USER_PASSWORD  sends the correct value as it is a "string" type. but  PW_FRAMED_IP_ADDRESS sends wrong value as its type is "ip" and I am sending string value..
If I  pass "ip" in forth arg.  `rc_avpair_add`   gives error of type conversion !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PW_FRAMED_IP_ADDRESS` wants an int for the fourth argument.

The easiest method is:

```
uint32_t framed_addr = 0;
inet_pton(AF_INET, "172.17.14.90", &framed_addr);
framed_addr = htonl(framed_addr); //network order
if (rc_avpair_add(rh, &send, PW_FRAMED_IP_ADDRESS,&framed_addr, -1, 0) == NULL)
            return ERROR_RC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but Framed-IP-Address is not string attribute. Here is more [detail](http://freeradius.org/rfc/rfc2865.html#Framed-IP-Address). Maybe

```
unsigned int ip=(unsigned int)inet_addr("172.17.14.90");
if (rc_avpair_add(rh, &send, PW_FRAMED_IP_ADDRESS, &ip, sizeof(ip), 0) == NULL)
```

helps you?